# Selenium checkbox not clicking

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Selenium checkbox not clicking problem

```
name="checkbox_2" type="checkbox"
```

my code:

```
IWebElement checkbox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("checkbox_2"));
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", checkbox);`
```

Comment: Can you click this check box manually? It looks grayed out or disabled.

Comment: I can manually click. selenium is gray when you try to click, but it doesn't set the tick mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the  desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.signup-agreement.checkbox-item.clearfix > label[for='memberContract'] input.customized.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched.ng-not-empty.ng-valid.ng-valid-required#memberContract"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='signup-agreement checkbox-item clearfix']/label[@for='memberContract']//input[@class='customized ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required' and @id='memberContract']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: they both didn't work. I don't think it's about waiting.

Comment: @mahvettin Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.